# ImageView diffrent scale types for orientation

Tags: android, android-layout

I use an `ImageView` that has to display after the following rules:

- always show full width for *landscape* and *portrait* images -this works now
- if the image is a landscape image center it in screen - it works
- **if the image is portrait show from top - don't cut the top** - it does not work

From the xml file

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Can I set the properties so the image will show correct even if it is a portrait or landscape image?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you pick `centerCrop` as your scale type. Of course it is going to get cropped.

Answer (score 1):

You may subclass `ImageView`, use `matrix` scaling and then override the `setFrame` method. Depending on the image size - whether it has portrait or landscape orientation - you will apply a different matrix. Please find an [example implementation here](https://gist.github.com/benvium/8578297) that aligns the image to the bottom edge and then crops off the top. As this is very similar to your requirements this might be a good starting point for further adjustments.

Comment: I am not referring at screen orientation but at images , the images come from server and they are portrait or landscape . I don t treat multiple device orientation , the app is for portrait use .

Comment: what are the properties that must be set for a image view to show from top and full width and keep aspect ratio ?